# Creating an aliased column in a dynamic SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to add in the `@tblName` variable as an aliased column - vanTbl, below -  in the dynamically executed `SELECT` statement - SQL keeps throwing an error

> Invalid Column Name

Perhaps this is some scope issue? Any suggestions much appreciated. Apologies in advance if this has been addressed somewhere, is too vague, etc.

```
DECLARE @tblName varchar(64)
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
     (SELECT DISTINCT t1.TABLE_NAME 
      FROM 
          (SELECT * 
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE (COLUMN_NAME = 'x_SECTION'
                  OR COLUMN_NAME = 'x_TABLE')
          ) t1
      GROUP BY t1.TABLE_NAME)

OPEN cursor1 

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @tblName

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' +@tblName+ ' as vanTbl,
 SECTION,   SHAPE, TABLENAME, x_SECTION, x_TABLE FROM ' +@tblName + ' 
 WHERE x_SECTION <> '' '''

EXEC(@sqlCommand)

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

Comment: Your cursor is just all wrong here. I assume you want to get more than 1 table? You don't have a loop here to do that. Also look at your dynamic sql, you do not have the tblName as a string literal which is what you want. The best way to debug dynamic sql is to select/print your dynamic sql and look at it. You should ALWAYS be doing that with dynamic sql because it is difficult to get it right.

Comment: This question is about the error when executing.

Comment: Personally I truly despise cursors because of the huge performance black hole they introduce. I would do this a little differently. I would leverage sys.columns to build a large query and then execute a single query with a number of UNION ALL.

Comment: I agree, but let's not side-track :)

Comment: How is recommending a better approach getting side tracked? If all we ever did was just answer the question and not even attempt to help the OP learn or fix the glaring issues in their code we are doing them a disservice. Pointing out logical flaws is all part of being helpful.

Comment: You have another logic problem - which you wont find without better testing. Your cursor selects tables that have at least one of the columns mentioned. They don't necessarily have both. Your dynamic sql statement assumes otherwise. You can also remove distinct - it does nothing since you also group by t1.TABLE_NAME. I suggest you add an order by clause for completeness. Order of rows is almost always a concern - eventually.

Answer (score 0):

tblName should be surrounded by extra quotes, since it is a string value:

```
 'SELECT DISTINCT ''' +@tblName+ ''' as vanTbl,
```

This will result in:

```
 'SELECT DISTINCT 'TBL_NAME' as vanTbl,
```

There seems to be an issue with there not being a loop in your cursor, but that will probably be another question. You should look at some cursor examples.

Comment: This is correct but only part of the issue. The OP has this in a cursor but there is no loop. :)

Comment: True, bat that is another issue.

Comment: Not really...it is all part of the same thing. Sure you fix the syntax error but didn't address the huge logical issue.

Comment: Again, the question is regarding the error message.

Comment: And the point in answering is to help them. Simply ignoring the fact that a cursor has no iteration makes for an incomplete response. If you don't help people learn they can't get better.

Comment: Hello there! Appreciate at ALL the advice and suggestions. Yes, I realize I'm not looping through the cursor, at this point. Just got stuck on why I couldn't add in the table name to the initial iteration's result. And, Sean, I appreciate the comments on alternatives to the 'cursor' approach. I'm quite new to any advanced SQL work so any and all suggestions much appreciate. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help with the issue in question :)